# Случайно создал бесконечный цикл и пк завис

Tags: python, pycharm

написал код в PyCharm:

```
s = []
a = input()
while a != "*":
    s.append(a)
```

Когда запустил появился заедающий звук в наушниках и пк завис, пришлось вырубать через кнопку.
Как поставить ограничение на загрузку ОЗУ? И на сколько большой вред я нанёс ОЗУ?

Comment: ОЗУ то ничего в итоге не будет. А вот на жёстком диске при перезагрузке кнопкой может что-нибудь и полететь.

Comment: Да и диску ничего не будет (с точки зрения железа). Есть теоретическая вероятность потерять некоторые данные, если шла их активная запись. И то это случается как правило при вырубании питания (диск, например, не успеет сбросить кеш). При ресете могут испортится только данные (ибо обработка данных может прекратиться в неожиданный для них момент), для железа это штатная работа (говорю как человек тесно связанный с разработкой чипов). Но когда комп "зависает", то в большинстве случаев активная запись прекращается и что-либо испортить более, чем это уже испорчено моментом зависания, не получится.

Answer (score 1):

Про вред для ПК и ОЗУ уже написал @GrAnd в [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1355404/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81#comment2404526_1355404). А код нужно исправить:

```
s = []
a = None
while a != "*":
    a=input()
    s.append(a)
```